Why is this bound correct?
I recently encountered the following statement:
Let $S:=\big\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x>0, y>0, z>0, x+y+z<7\big\}$.
Let $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$
such that:
$$f(x,y,z) = \ln x+2\ln y +3 \ln z +\ln (7-x-y-z) $$
and let $K := \big\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x\geq \big(\frac{2}{7}\big)^6, y\geq \big(\frac{2}{7}\big)^6\, z\geq \big(\frac{2}{7}\big)^6, x+y+z \leq 7-\big(\frac{2}{7}\big)^6 \big\}$
then for all $(x,y,z)\in S\setminus K$:
$$f(x,y,z)\leq 6 \ln \max \{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\}+\ln \min\{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\}$$
I can't seem to figure out how they got this bound and why it is correct.
I would have gone something like:
$$f(x,y,z) \leq 7 \ln \max \{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\} $$
Where did their separation into max and min come from?

Writing $2 \ln y$ as the sum $ \ln y + \ln y$ and similarly $ 3 \ln z =  \ln z+ \ln z +\ln z$, we can see $f(x,y,z)$ as a sum of 7 terms. At least one of these terms is a minimal term. We separate this term, which writes $\ln \min\{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\}$, and majorate the six others by the maximal term to get
$$f(x,y,z)\leq 6 \ln \max \{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\}+\ln \min\{x,y,z, 7-x-y-z\}. $$

Why "At least one of these terms is a minimal term."?

Write for exemple u = a + b + c + d. Then either a, b, c or d is minimal among the terms of the sum.
